# Access Violation when writing to pointer variables in dynamically allocated classes

Tags: c++, memory-management, access-violation

Ok so the title doesn't explain my situation very well so I'll try to explain a little better here:

Here is part of my class structure:

```
ObjectView (abstract class)

ShipView : ObjectView (child of object view)
```

In a method I create a new ShipView:

```
ShipView *shipview (in header file).

shipview = new ShipView(in main part of code).
```

I then run `shipview->Initialise();`
to set everything up in the new class.

But when I get to any lines of code that try to write to a pointer declared in the ObjectView class it won't allow me to do so and gives me an Access Violation message.
The message that I get is below:

```
"Unhandled exception at 0x00a0cf1c in AsteroidGame.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xbaadf011."
```

For example this line:

```
_ObjectData = new Model[mesh->mNumVertices];
```

will give me the error.

Just fyi I have put this in the header file:

```
struct Model{
    GLfloat x,y,z;
    GLfloat nX,nY,nZ;
    GLfloat u,v;
};

Model *_ObjectData;
```

However if I was to do something along the lines of

```
Model *_ObjectData = new Model[mesh->mNumVertices];
```

(declare and initialise all at once)

it would work....

It's like it doesn't know the header file is there, or the class has not been properly constructed therefore the memory has not been allocated properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

***EDIT***
Header File:

```
class ObjectView
{
public:
    ObjectView(void);
    virtual ~ObjectView(void);

    void Initialise(std::string objectpath, std::string texturepath);
    void InitialiseVBO(const aiScene* sc);  

    void RenderObject();

    virtual void ScaleObject() = 0;
    virtual void TranslateObject() = 0;
    virtual void RotateObject() = 0;

protected:
    struct Model{
        GLfloat x,y,z;
        GLfloat nX,nY,nZ;
        GLfloat u,v;
    };
    Model *_ObjectData;

    struct Indices{
        GLuint x,y,z;
    };
    Indices *_IndicesData;  

    TextureLoader _textureloader;
    GLuint _objectTexture;

    GLuint _objectVBO;
    GLuint _indicesVBO;

    int _numOfIndices;
};
```

Code:

```
void ObjectView::InitialiseVBO(const aiScene* sc)
{   
    const aiMesh* mesh = sc->mMeshes[0];

    _ObjectData = new Model[mesh->mNumVertices];

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < mesh->mNumVertices; i++)
    {
        _ObjectData[i].x = mesh->mVertices[i].x;
        _ObjectData[i].y = mesh->mVertices[i].y;
        _ObjectData[i].z = mesh->mVertices[i].z;

        _ObjectData[i].nX = mesh->mNormals[i].x;
        _ObjectData[i].nY = mesh->mNormals[i].y;
        _ObjectData[i].nZ = mesh->mNormals[i].z;

        _ObjectData[i].u = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].x;
        _ObjectData[i].v = 1-mesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].y;
    }

    glGenBuffers(1, &_objectVBO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _objectVBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Model) * mesh->mNumVertices, &_ObjectData[0].x, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    _IndicesData = new Indices[mesh->mNumFaces];

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < mesh->mNumFaces; ++i)
    {
        for (unsigned int a = 0; a < 3; ++a)
        {
            unsigned int temp = mesh->mFaces[i].mIndices[a];
            if(a == 0)
                _IndicesData[i].x = temp;
            else if(a == 1)
                _IndicesData[i].y = temp;
            else
                _IndicesData[i].z = temp;
        }
    }

    glGenBuffers(1, &_indicesVBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _indicesVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Indices) * mesh->mNumFaces, _IndicesData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    _numOfIndices = sizeof(Indices) * mesh->mNumFaces;

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    delete _ObjectData;
    delete _IndicesData;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If

`_ObjectData = new Model[mesh->mNumVertices];`

crashes while

`Model *_ObjectData = new Model[mesh->mNumVertices];`

doesn't, it certainly looks like your object hasn't been initialized.
My psychic debugger suggests that you have declared a different variable, also called `shipview`, which is what you're calling `Initialize()` on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll take a look but I'm sure I haven't. I create the class in the constructor of another class so it's all initialised... I'll take a look and report back :)

Comment: Oh man oh man, how stupid I am. It turns out I was making a ShipView class but it was going out of scope after the constructor I was making it in.... durrrrrrrrr hurp derp lol. Thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: No worries. BTW: I noticed that you're deleting `_ObjectData` and `_IndicesData` in `Initialize()`, so they don't need to be member variables. If you make them local to the function you'll never access them by mistake. There's a bigger problem with them, though: you should use `delete []` since you're allocating arrays. Weird and terrible things can happen otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

0xbaadf011 is probably an offset from 0xbaadf00d which is a hexadecimal synonym for Bad Food. It is certainly an uninitialized pointer.

You are obviously not setting your pointers before using them. I suggest looking at the call stack when it crashes, set a breakpoint at one of the functions above your crash, then restart the program and run it line by line until you find the pointer that is set to 0xbaadf011 or 0xbaadf00d. Then figure out where you were supposed to set that pointer.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the info! Still very strange as I am sure I have initialised everything. I shall report back asap.       On a side note, if I create an instance like ShipView shipview.... shipview.blah(); then everything works fine......... :S

Comment: Hmm, well I can't seem to find anything wrong by looking at the code. The pointers of the class are definitely not being initialised which is weird because they sould be.... :s I'll add the header file and the class to the initial post...